# What is the numbers separator when comma is used as decimal separator?

Tags: numbers, separator

As we know, in many places people use comma as decimal separator. My question is: how they write a formula such as sum(1, 2, 3)? I don't know how people there separate numbers in that formula.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally use a semi-colon “;” as a universal solution.